# SSAS: creating a relation between my dimension table and existing time dimension

Tags: ssas

I have a dimension table that has two date fields. I need to create a relation to time dimension for both of these fields in order to filter the data by Year/Quarter/date (hierarchy that I defined in time dimension). I'm new at this and a bit lost, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Link both the columns of your dimension table to existing time dimension table in DSV. Create a measure group from that dimension table. Your existing time dimension will then act like a [role playing dimension](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3117/defining-role-playing-dimensions-for-sql-server-analysis-services/) in SSAS cube. You can pick 2 dates from two time dimensions to filter your data.

You can also [avoid role playing dimension](http://visual-intelligence.nu/how-to-avoid-role-playing-dimensions-in-ssas/) by doing some changes in your design.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly I would establish this relationship in my [Fact Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact_table).

One option is to join the Date Dimension twice over (once for each of your date fields). To create the relationship the first option is to [Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189049.aspx) for each of the date fields so that the relationship is translated into your cube. Another option is within the DataSourceView of SQL Server Data Tools > Analysis Services, pull in the source table for your Date Dimension and source table for your Fact table, and create the Primary/Foreign key relationships there.

Another option could be to split this setup into multiple Fact tables each with a single reference to the Date dimension **so that you could the plot separate measures to the same graph** on the same date axis. See [How to avoid Role Playing Dimension](http://visual-intelligence.nu/how-to-avoid-role-playing-dimensions-in-ssas/). This would also require that you create your Primary/Foreign key relationship in either the source tables or the DataSourceView as mentioned previously.